# Starting Bitbucket Server in Ansible

Tags: shell, ubuntu, vagrant, ansible, bitbucket-server

I'm using Vagrant and Ansible to create my Bitbucket Server on Ubuntu 15.10. I have the server setup complete and working but I have to manually run the start-webapp.sh script to start the server each time I reprovision the server.

I have the following task in my Bitbucket role in Ansible and when I increase the verbosity I can see that I get a positive response from the server saying it will be running at http://localhost/ but when I go to the URL the server isn't on. If I then SSH in to the server and run the script myself, getting the exact same response after running the script I can see the startup webpage.

```
- name: Start the Bitbucket Server
  become: yes
  shell: /bitbucket-server/atlassian-bitbucket-4.7.1/bin/start-webapp.sh
```

Any advice would be great on how to fix this.

Thanks,

Sam

Answer (score 2):

Probably better to change that to an init script and use the service module to start it. For example, see [this role](https://github.com/pantarei/ansible-role-bitbucket/) for installing bitbucket...

Otherwise, you're subject to HUP and other issues from running processes under an ephemeral session.